# New object using object's class instance

Tags: php, object, instance

Today I just discovered that in php you can do :

```
$instance = new MyObject();

// Here $instance->getName() == 'First Instance'
$instance->setName('First Instance');

// Here $newInstance->getName() == null
$newInstance = new $instance();
```

Obviously `$newInstance` is a valid 'MyObject' object.

Can someone tell me what this way to go involve and if it is or isn't a must NOT do?

Thx mates !

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The last line of that code makes no sense. I would have expected it to fatal, but apparently not O_o

Comment: I am using a function which takes an object in parameter, which I don't know the class, use a function to get more details about the object then cast a new class instance sending using all the details.
I create a new class because this function is part of a project where I get object details using an API and each function which get information from this API return a 'new MyObject($apiResults)' so I want to keep this way to go even for this function which is more general...

Answer (score 1):

You need to use what is called a "Singleton Design Pattern" to achieve your goal, which, if I'm not wrong is that you want to use the same Object, every time an Object of the class is created.

```
class Singleton {
private static $instance;

public function __construct() {
        if (isset(self::$instance)) {
            $object         = __CLASS__;
            self::$instance = new $object;
            return self::$instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Here, the constructor checks if there is already an instance of the class, if there is, it returns that object itself. Else it creates a new one.